# MDX - Filter a measure by another measure of a same dimension

Tags: filter, mdx

I must use [ZONE].[MY_ZONE_1] ON ROWS because this is a group of zones with different names starting with "a zone that starts with MY_ZONE_1" which I filtered and set as [FILTERED ZONE].
I need to show the products available in stock (min 1 piece) in [ZONE].[MY_ZONE_1] but are not in stock in [ZONE].[MY_ZONE_2]. So the dimension I use here to filter the result is [ZONE].[MY_ZONE_1], but can't filter by [ZONE].[MY_ZONE_2] because i can't use the dimension [ZONE] on 2 different axes.

Something like:

> select article_code
>   where (stock_in_zone1 >= 1) && (stock_in_zone2 is null or = 0)

---

```
WITH 
  SET [FILTERED ZONE] AS 
    {
      {
        Filter
        (
          [ZONE].[ZONE].MEMBERS
         ,
            Instr
            (
              [ZONE].[ZONE].CurrentMember.Name
             ,"a zone that starts with MY_ZONE_1"
            )
          > 0
        )
      }
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AVAILABLE STOCK] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[STOCK] < 1
     ,null
     ,[Measures].[STOCK]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AVAILABLE STOCK]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    CrossJoin
    (
      [FILTERED ZONE]
     ,[ARTICLE CODE].[ARTICLE CODE].MEMBERS
    ) ON 1
FROM [MyCube];
```

Answer (score 1):

I have a tendency of breaking the rule of keeping things simple but hopefully you get the idea of how I'm breaking things down into several sets to try to help:

```
WITH 
  SET [AllArtCodes] AS 
    [ARTICLE CODE].[ARTICLE CODE].MEMBERS 
  SET [AllArtCodes_zone1Greater1] AS //<<to find the article codes in zone 1 with [Measures].[STOCK] >= 1
    Filter
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [AllArtCodes]
       ,[ZONE].[MY_ZONE_1]
      )
     ,
      [Measures].[STOCK] >= 1
    ) 
  SET [AllArtCodes_zone2nullZero] AS //<<to find the article codes in zone 2 with [Measures].[STOCK] = 0 (this should cover the null option as well)
    Filter
    (
      NonEmpty
      (
        [AllArtCodes]
       ,[ZONE].[MY_ZONE_2]
      )
     ,
      [Measures].[STOCK] = 0
    ) 
  SET [intersectAbove] AS //<< narrow to common members of above two custom sets
    Intersect
    (
      [AllArtCodes_zone1Greater1]
     ,[AllArtCodes_zone2nullZero]
    ) 
  SET [FILTERED ZONE] AS 
    {
      {
        Filter
        (
          [ZONE].[ZONE].MEMBERS
         ,
            Instr
            (
              [ZONE].[ZONE].CurrentMember.Name
             ,"a zone that starts with MY_ZONE_1"
            )
          > 0
        )
      }
    } 
  MEMBER [Measures].[AVAILABLE STOCK] AS 
    IIF
    (
      [Measures].[STOCK] < 1
     ,null
     ,[Measures].[STOCK]
    ) 
SELECT 
  NON EMPTY 
    {[Measures].[AVAILABLE STOCK]} ON 0
 ,NON EMPTY 
    [FILTERED ZONE] * [intersectAbove] ON 1 //<<filtered set here
FROM [MyCube];
```